# multiple cases in c# chatbot

Tags: c#, case

```
case "hello": 
case "hi" :
// in the message box im trying to get multiple responces
Console.writeLine("what's up");  
break;
```

How would I give it multiple responces from "hi" and "Hello" , I'm just wondering if there's any way using this switch statement or if I'd have to write it all from strings? I'm a bit of a noob at this at the moment, thanks

Comment: You can't "fall through" in a C# `switch`.  You could use `goto`, I believe, but that's generally not favored.

Comment: Ah okay I thought not, I've searched quite a lot and had no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both options like this :

```
switch (string)
{
 case "hello": case "hi: case "hi there":          
// Do Something
break;
case 4: case 5: case 6: 
// Do Something
break;   
}
```

Goodluck.